# How to prevent escaping of text in C# for ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, escaping

I have the following code that adds a new-line to the browser prompt for my web app written for ASP.NET:

```
RectangleHotSpot rhs = new RectangleHotSpot();
rhs.HotSpotMode = HotSpotMode.Navigate;
rhs.AlternateText = "Line one&#013;Line Two"; //New-line to conform with FF
rhs.NavigateUrl = "my URL";

ImageMap.HotSpots.Add(rhs);
```

But for some reason 'rhs.AlternateText' gets escaped into:

> "Line one& amp ;#013;Line Two"

when I view source in the web browser. (I had to add spaces above because this site escapes it too :)

Is there any way to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    public class RectangleHotSpot : System.Web.UI.WebControls.HotSpot
{
    private string _strAlt;
    public override string AlternateText
    {
        get
        {
            return _strAlt;
        }
        set
        {
            this._strAlt = value;
        }
    }

    public override string GetCoordinates()
    {
        return String.Empty; // You'll need to fill this in.
    }

    protected override string MarkupName
    {
        get { return String.Empty; } // This too.
    }
}
```

The GetCoordinates and MarkupName are required as part of the abstract members, but I'm not familiar with the Rectangle Hot Spot class, so I'm not sure what you would substitue there.

Comment: This doesn't work either. The value is getting encoded by the parent control. At this point I would just make the control you need from scratch. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful! :(

Comment: Thanks anyway. It seems like this is a built-in function of ASP.NET to encode those strings?

Comment: Yes. When using the HtmlTextWriter it is seemingly calling .WriteEncodedText(string). Out of pure frustration I even tried overriding the render function of the ImageMap control and manually remove Attributes["alt"] and re-added Attributes["alt"] with a hard-coded copy of the string in your example, but no modifications are being made to that input value until it is written to the output stream from what I can tell. I really stopped relying on WebControls by the time 2.0 was released. So many headaches can be saved by whipping up a custom control especially if you start building a library.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Indeed it is frustrating. I'll probably end up just "composing" it via a pure HTML. I'm not really good at writing my own controls ...

Comment: It's really simple. Consider the following and go from there:

public class TestControl : System.Web.UI.Control
{
  protected override Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
  {
    writer.WriteLine("Hi world.");
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

That's because that is the correct (W3C) way to use it when it appears in attribute quotes. I'm not familiar with the exact control you are using, but see below for an example:

```
<img src="img/wrong.jpg" alt="This is the wrong way &#013; because the ampersand is not encoded properly for attributes" />

<img src="img/correct.jpg" alt="This is the right way &amp;#013 because the ampersand IS escaped and the browser will read &amp; as just an ampersand plus the code, which is what you want." />
```

Comment: If the line he is outputting is in attribute quotes in the HTML, then it is correct like that. You have to double escape: once for HTML, and another for attributes.

Comment: What I'm getting it, is that you don't want to change it. It's correct the way it's doing it for you.

Comment: If the output is NOT enclosed within attribute quotes, then try using the HtmlString object like so:
    rhs.AlternateText = new System.Web.HtmlString("Line one&#013;Line Two");

Comment: Actually, just post the output HTML output as it currently is, and I'll be able to tell you what it should be.

Comment: Having removed all tags/attributes not essential for this question, the resulting HTML should be: <area title="Line one&#013;Line Two" alt="Line one&#013;Line Two" />

Comment: Hmm. Not sure there is a way to do this without just creating a custom class. Are those really all the properties you need? Would take all of 5 minutes to make a custom control to do what you need. I know some other classes like the Image control do that with Alternate Text, and I have just simply overridden the property, but it appears that RectangleHotSpot cannot be inherited.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Can you post your override and I'll mark it an an answer. PS. Too bad MS didn't think about it...